# Difference between def and val in Scala

Tags: scala

loop is defined as below:

```
 def loop : Boolean = loop
```

When x is defined as: `def x = loop` then "x: Boolean" is shown in console.

and

When x is defined as: `val x = loop` then it goes to infinite loop

I know def is using call by-name and val is using call by-value. Even though this point about loop defined above is not much clear.

Comment: is your loop an infinite loop?

Comment: can you post the definition of your method body, what exactly you're trying to do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`def` doesn't evaluate the right-hand side of the assignment. Just like

```
def f(x : Int) = x + 2
```

doesn't (in this case logically can't) evaluate `f` of anything, just defines what the function `f`, means, neither `def loop : Boolean = loop` nor `def x = loop` evaluate anything. You are just defining a function to be executed at some other point.

But `val`s do require the right-hand side of the assignment to be evaluated. So `val x = loop` tries to execute the expression on the right-hand side. Trying to evaluate `loop` never terminates, though, since `loop` is an infinite loop.

Answer (score 9):

The call-by-name or call-by-value distinction seems less useful in this case, because neither your `x`, nor your `loop` take any arguments.

But there are two other ways in which `val` and `def` differ.

First distinction is: eager vs. lazy.

- The right hand side of `val` is evaluated *eagerly*, as soon as the `val` is *defined*.
- The right hand side of `def` is evaluated *lazily*, as soon as the
  `def` is *accessed*.

For example:

```
def x = { println("x is evaluated"); 42 } 
val y = { println("y is evaluated"); 42 }
x
```

Will print:

```
y is evaluated
x is evaluated
```

because `y` is evaluated immediately, whereas `x` is evaluated only when we call it.

The other difference is whether the result of the computation is cached or not:

- The value of `val` is evaluated *once*, and then cached
- The value of `def` is evaluated *every time* we call the function

This is why

```
def dice = { new scala.util.Random().nextInt(6) + 1 }
val once = { new scala.util.Random().nextInt(6) + 1 }

println(dice + " <-> " + once)
println(dice + " <-> " + once)
println(dice + " <-> " + once)
println(dice + " <-> " + once)
```

will output:

```
5 <-> 6
4 <-> 6
6 <-> 6
5 <-> 6
```

that is, `dice` is a more or less useful random number generator that generates values `1-6`, whereas `once` is a rather useless random value that is fixed once it's created.

---

Now, you can think of a 2x2-table with eager-vs-lazy in one dimension, and cached-vs-not-cached on the other:

- `val` is **eager** and **cached**
- `lazy val` is **lazy** and **cached** (so are memoized `def`s)
- `def` is **lazy** and **uncached**
- There is not really **eager** and **uncached**, because computing something and then immediately throwing it away is not very useful. Maybe there is one exception that gets pretty close: the entry point of the program, because even though `def main` is a `def`, it always gets called anyway, so in a sense it's both kind-of eager and uncached.

In your code, `loop` is essentially a tail-recursive version of the non-terminating

```
def loop: Boolean = { while (true) {}; true }
```

but since `loop` is a `def`, and therefore lazy, the right hand side is not evaluated when you define it.

If you now define

```
def x = loop
```

nothing is happening still, because `x` is also lazy, so the right hand side is again not evaluated.

But if you define

```
val x = loop
```

then `x` is a `val`, thus its right hand side is evaluated *eagerly*. On the right hand side of the definition, there is an invocation of `loop`. Now `loop` is accessed, and since it is a `def`, it now evaluates its body, and goes into an infinite loop.

Comment: I think it is confusing to introduce the concept of lazy evaluation here.  Both `val` and `def` are evaluated immediately, it is just that `val` defines a value whereas `def` defines a function that returns a value. That function is only evaluated when it is called, because that is how functions work.

Comment: The body of a `def` is not "evaluated immediately", for any notion of *evaluation* that I'm aware of. A parameterless `def` can also define a single value, as long as it is deterministic (i.e. not dependent on random number generators etc.). For example, `def x = 42` is a `def` that defines a value. The difference to `val` would be that the `42` is stored in the bytecode of the function, whereas a `val x = 42` would be stored as a member of a class instance. Finally, "lazy" is just a short way to write "only evaluated when it is called".