# Scala Value Definitions: Confusing case for def and val evaluation

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Since and I quote from Martin Odersky:

- The **def** form is “by-name”, its right hand side is evaluated on each
  use.
- The right-hand side of a **val** definition is evaluated at the point of
  the definition itself.

In this case:

- `def loop: Boolean = loop`
- `val x = loop // Leads to an infinite loop`

In this case:

- `val y: Boolean = y // Evaluated to false`

I'm a little confused why:

- `val x = loop // doesn't get evaluated to false?`

Comment: Because in order to evaluate the value of `loop` you need first to evaluate the value of `loop`. It's a recursive call without escape condition

Comment: The emphasis of the question is strange. It's obvious that `val x = loop` should just hang forever. What's not so obvious is why `val y: Boolean = y` does anything at all.

Comment: Thank you Andrey for rephrasing my question. I believe that the emphasis of the question is strange as I didn't know the underlying procedures for both def and val.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use

```
val y: Boolean = y
```

in statement position inside method body, it doesn't evaluate to anything at all, because it gives a compile time error:

```
error: forward reference extends over definition of value y
```

However, if you use it as a member variable, it compiles to a separate private variable initialized with `_`, a getter `def`, and a separate initializer:

```
private[this] val y: Boolean = _;
<stable> <accessor> def y(): Boolean = XeqX.this.y;

[...]

def <init>(): WhateverYourClassIsCalled.type = {
  XeqX.super.<init>();
  XeqX.this.y = XeqX.this.y();
  ()
}
```

Since `_` on right hand side for booleans evaluates to default value `false`, by the time you access it in initializer, the member `y` is already set to `false`.

---

In contrast to that

```
def loop: Boolean = loop
```

never terminates once it's called. Therefore

```
val x = loop
```

tries to evaluate its right hand side immediately, and then hangs forever.

---

Here is [another answer for a similar problem (again, difference between `def` and `val`)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49144271/difference-between-def-and-val-in-scala/49145657#49145657).

Comment: Thanks Andrey for your answer.